# Convert Rows into Columns with same values

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Let's say I've a table

```
ID | Item      | Purchased  
17 | Chocolate | 1304       
17 | Biscuit   | 1209           
17 | Jelly     |  657            
17 | Milk      | 2234  
18 | Chocolate | 1000
19 | Jelly     |2387
```

I want to convert the rows into columns for each Item through Pivot tables in Excel

```
ID | Chocolate_Purchased | Biscuit_Purchased | Jelly_Purchased | Milk_Purchased
17 | 1304                | 1209              | 657            | 2234
18 | 1000                |                   |                |
19 |                     |                   | 2387           |
```

How do I do that in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is with a Pivot table, although you may need to do some massaging to get exactly the output format you want.
With ID-->Rows; Itme-->Columns and Purchased--> Values, you can easily produce a Pivot looking like:

[image]

And you can do all kinds of different things with the formatting.